# URL with query string is not matched

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to match following URL which isn't working with the rewrite rule:

https://www.example.com/forums/showthread.php?t=12345

```
RewriteRule ^forums\/showthread\.php$ "https\:\/\/www\.google\.com" [L]
```

However, https://www.example.com/forums/showthread.php (without the query string) is matched and redirects to google.

I also did try a rewrite condition to explicitly match a query parameter.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} t=(\d+)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^forums\/showthread\.php "https\:\/\/www\.google\.be" [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a wildcard `(.*)` before the end of line `$` like so:

`RewriteRule ^forums\/showthread\.php(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.google\.com" [L]`

Example and explanation here: https://regex101.com/r/o256NR/1